# Create a simple menu with Java

Tags: java, menu

Am trying to find Java code that can produce the following kind of output when the `private static void main...`is called, am running the code on Command Prompt so I need java menu code to give me this

```
    C) Create new cargo <name> <weight> <strength>
    L) Load cargo from dock <stackIndex>
    U) Unload cargo from ship <srcStackIndex>
    M) Move cargo between stacks <srcStackIndex> <dstStackIndex>
    K) Clear dock
    P) Print ship stacks
    S) Search for cargo <name>
    Q) Quit
```

I have tried searching online for related code with no avail please help...

Comment: You can write it yourself, if it's menu it's mostly `text/String`, I think this shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Am not good with java menus so i need help

Comment: Use ```System.out.println("your text here")``` to print a line on console. e.g ```System.out.println("C) Create new cargo <name> <weight> <strength>")```

Comment: That might make my software incosistent, is there no way i ca use Java menus to do it?

Comment: @CodeTiger Do you want your menu to be as a console output or should it have GUI.

Comment: @kil Gore, it should be console output?

Comment: @CodeTiger If you want it as console output you can use `sout`. As the Osama mention above `System.out.println("C) Create new cargo <name> <weight> <strength>")`

Comment: Okay am gonna take his advice

Comment: @CodeTiger If you need it differently just explain it, I will try to help you. But the question you've provided above that is how console output looks like.

Comment: How do i process the choice of the user and call method is my problem

Comment: Say user choose option ```L)```,I need to capture that and call specific method from associated class object

Comment: @CodeTiger Take a look at the answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do a switch/case e.g.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("C) Create new cargo <name> <weight> <strength>");
        System.out.println("L) Load cargo from dock <stackIndex>");
        System.out.println("U) Unload cargo from ship <srcStackIndex>");
        System.out.println("M) Move cargo between stacks <srcStackIndex> <dstStackIndex>");
        System.out.println("K) Clear dock");
        System.out.println("P) Print ship stacks");
        System.out.println("S) Search for cargo <name>");
        System.out.println("Q) Quit");

        String options = null;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); // Capturing the input
        do {
            options = scan.nextLine();
            switch (options) {
                case "C":
                    // do what you want
                    break;
                case "L":
                    // do what you want
                    break;
                case "U":
                    // do what you want
                    break;
                case "M":
                    break;
                    // Add the rest of your cases
            }
        } while (!options.equals("Q")); // quitting the program
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you :))

Comment: That i exactly the kind of logic i needed

Comment: Despite your answer being correct, you shouldn't be answering a question from a member who didn't try to solve it fist. We are here to help others when their code is wrong, not to make homework.

Comment: You didnt define ```choice```

Comment: @CodeTiger I forgot to change it, sry

Answer (score 0):

You can just print every line out with:
`System.out.println("Put text here");`

Then you can use the Scanner from the `java.util`